# How to make (1,1) mean (1cm,1cm) in TikZ? (Setting the units of coordinates)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a picture in TikZ and I'd like to change the basic units of the coordinates I specify. I know I could just `scale` the picture, but I don't want to do that. For any given coordinate, I can write `(1cm,1cm)` etc for each coordinate, but I'd rather specify the "units" I want to use separately... Or for example make `(1,1)` mean `(5ex,10ex)`...

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See my answer, you can use `x=..., y=....` and it's possible to use macro to adjust `x=\myx, y=\myy`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default yes but you can compare the next results

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2cm,y=-1cm] 
  \draw(0,0)--(1,1);    
\end{tikzpicture}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=5,y=5] 
  \draw(0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=28.45274,y=28.45274] 
  \draw(0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

In the last code, we can see that without unit `x` and `y`are defined with `pt`

To complete the answer :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)--(600,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Latex Error: ... Dimension too large. The unit is the cm.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01 cm]
  \draw (0,0)--(600 cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

again Latex Error: ... Dimension too large because 600 cm is a length and TeX uses only lengths < 575 cm.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01 cm]
  \draw (0,0)--(600,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is correct ! 600 < `$2^{31}-1$` . 600 is a integer and not a length and now 600 gives 6 cm

Comment: I see, I was trying to be too clever: I was trying things like `[canvas cs:x=1cm,y=cm]` but that gave me errors. I didn't think to just try `x=...` Thanks!