# Coordinates unit in pt although default is cm in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, unit-of-measure

As we know that in TikZ, if unit is not mentioned in the coordinate in TikZ, it takes `cm` by default.

When I extract the coordinates, I was expecting the unit as `cm`. But TikZ shows the unit in the coordinate as `pt`.

How does TikZ determine the unit of measure in a coordinate if no unit is specified.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{zigzag/.style={decorate,decoration=zigzag}}
\begin{document}

\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c) at (0,-2);
  \coordinate (d) at (4,-2);
  \coordinate (e) at (2,-4);
  \draw[thick,red,zigzag,postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.7 with { \coordinate (x); },
        mark=at position 0.5 with { \coordinate (singularity); },
    },
    decorate
  }] (-2,0) coordinate(a) -- (2,0) coordinate(b);

  \draw[thick,fill=blue!20] (c) -- (b) -- (d) -- (e) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick,postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark = at position 0.7 with \coordinate (y);
    },
    decorate
  }] (a) -- (c);
  \draw[thick,red,dashed] (x) -- (y);

  \node[above = 10ex of singularity,red] (sn) {singularity};
  \draw[red,->] (sn) -- ($(singularity)+(0,1)$);
  \ExtractCoordinate{x};
  \node[above] at (\XCoord,\YCoord) {(\XCoord,\YCoord)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but the information may be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20069/579

Comment: Barbara I would like to know the default unit of measure when unit of measure is not mentioned

Comment: Internally Ti*k*Z works with pt. You have a coordinate system in which the unit vectors have length 1cm. Does that make sense? The IMHO clearest discussion on this can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/121799 .

Comment: How did you measure the distance though? How did you make sure you are not magnifying the document when measuring?

Comment: @zyy As far as I can see, there is only the word singularity, not a real singularity, so you can use the Euclidean metric to a good approximation. ;-)

Comment: @marmot so if Unit of measure is not mentioned, it take pt by default.  Is that right ?

Comment: @subhamsoni Almost but not quite. If it is a vector with components `(x,y)`, then this vector will become `x e_x + y e_y` where `e_x=(1cm,0)` and `e_y=(0,1cm)` by default. On the other hand, if you say something like `[xshift=7]` then this will produce a shift by `7pt`. So, in a way, for vectorial quantities the default are cm (in the above sense). Effectively `1` in `\draw circle(1);` gets also interpreted as `1cm`. But I cannot express it better than LoopSpace in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31606/121799, especially in a comment.

Comment: @marmot in that case the system should express in `cm`.  But it is expressed as `pt`. Which is surprising to me.

Comment: Welcome to the club of those who get continuously surprised by Ti*k*Z. ;-) More seriously, everything you do with the `calc` syntax is done in `pt` unless you explicitly instruct Ti*k*Z to behave differently. You can convert the distances in cm if you want, of course. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @marmot meaning with `calc` the unit of measure changes from `cm` to `pt`. Right?

Comment: @marmot Oh, sure, you are correct.

Comment: _If you do not provide a unit, as in `(2,1)`, you specify a point in pgf’s xy-coordinate system. By default, the unit x-vector goes 1cm to the right and the unit y-vector goes 1cm upward._ (p.122, pgfmanual, v3.1.1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always convert everything from pt to cm or back by multiplying by the ratio `1pt/1cm` or its inverse. (If that's not what you're after, I will be happy to remove the post.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{zigzag/.style={decorate,decoration=zigzag}}
\begin{document}

\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (c) at (0,-2);
  \coordinate (d) at (4,-2);
  \coordinate (e) at (2,-4);
  \draw[thick,red,zigzag,postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0.7 with { \coordinate (x); },
        mark=at position 0.5 with { \coordinate (singularity); },
    },
    decorate
  }] (-2,0) coordinate(a) -- (2,0) coordinate(b);

  \draw[thick,fill=blue!20] (c) -- (b) -- (d) -- (e) -- cycle;
  \draw[thick,postaction={
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark = at position 0.7 with \coordinate (y);
    },
    decorate
  }] (a) -- (c);
  \draw[thick,red,dashed] (x) -- (y);

  \node[above = 10ex of singularity,red] (sn) {singularity};
  \draw[red,->] (sn) -- ($(singularity)+(0,1)$);
  \ExtractCoordinate{x};
  \node[above] at (\XCoord,\YCoord) {%
  (\pgfmathparse{\XCoord*1pt/1cm}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,cm,%
  \pgfmathparse{\YCoord*1pt/1cm}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}\,cm)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]